# Multiple Mapviews in one ViewController which causing memory Leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

In my app user  shown current location(First Mkmapview ) and last five locations(Five locations with respective mapviews) stored. so, total i'm using six mapviews in one ViewController which is causing memory issue . Please  help me to over come this memory issue. Any help appreciated

Comment: why to use different maps in different view controllers? Cant you just change the locations on the same map?

Comment: I added six mapviews on scrollview with paging enabled. so, each page shows one mapview with relative location.

Comment: better to have one mapview. and whenever you have scrolled change locations instead of mapview

Comment: you mean i has change frame of mapview in page 1 to page 2 with updating location

Comment: If we change the locations like you said then the animation might be not clear. i.e we may not get the same animation like the scroll view scrolling effect